# How do I get rid of an extra row in a matplotlib colormap?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have created the following colormap in matplotlib:

[image: Colormap]

I can't figure out how to get rid of the extra row, nor what is causing it.

My code is below:

```
# Create colormap
c = pcolor(data)
set_cmap('jet')
c = pcolor(data, edgecolors='w',linewidths = '3')

# Set x and y-axes
xticks = np.arange(.5,len(x_labels),1)
xlabels = x_labels
plt.xticks(xticks, xlabels)
xlabel('Species')
yticks = np.arange(.5,len(y_labels),1)
ylabels = y_labels
plt.yticks(yticks, ylabels)
ylabel('Experiments')

# Set the range of values to between 0 and 1
plt.clim(-1,1)
#colorbar()
# Either save to file or show
if filename:
    savefig(filename + '.png')
else:
    show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Chris' explicit answer always works. An alternative solution is to tell matplotlib what you want and let the system take care of the details. You want a tight axis, so insert

```
axis('tight')
```

before the `show()`. Alternatively `axis(image)` also works, wih the arguably pleasant side effect of making the cells square.

Answer (score 0):

How about just changing the y-axis limits using `matplotlib.pyplot.ylim(ymax=7.5)`.